# Can the GLBC load balancer be used with gunicorn sync workers

Tags: gunicorn, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a microservice run with gunicorn:

> command: ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "a.b:API", "--access-logfile=-","--error-logfile=-"]

I configured a readiness and liveness probe:

```
readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health-check
            port: 8000
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health-check
    port: 8000
    initialDelaySeconds: 15
    periodSeconds: 10
    timeoutSeconds: 2
```

The microservice has a very low load (about 5 requests per minute) and there are 3 copies of this microservice.
Despite this fact every 2 hours the health check is failing because of timeout getting the headers.

I found an issue connected:
https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1194
but what puzzles me is that the health check is not using the load balancer.

Could it be that the [glbc load balancer](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md) is somehow catching the connections and not letting them release?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "connections being cached by GLBC LB? For clarification on how LB and HC work with GKE. Health checks do not use load balancers, they are sent directly to the backend path configured in the HC configuration HC w/ ingress will match the liveness probe path
yet again, the request does not go through the LB and as per Gunicorn, it seems to be resolved it with a newer version of gunicorn. Did you update your Grunicorn following Github post?

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1194

Comment: I use the latest gunicorn. So I don't know why this happens. What I thought Is that maybe glbc sometimes  doesn't release connections for the normal requests so that the health checks won't get served by the sync workers

Comment: Please note that LB do not normally keep connections open unless there is an incoming external request. [LB keep-alive](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) time, is normally set to about 10 minutes (600 seconds) for the average backend so, you can configure the web server software used by your backends so that its keepalive timeout is longer than 600 seconds to prevent connections from being closed. Also keep in mind, depending on how this is configured may lead to more 502 server errors.

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang Did you find the answer? I'm also struggling with the same issue